# listen() queue length in socket-programing in c?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-protocols, listen

I have written two pair of codes(`server.c` and `client.c`) in Linux. One for UNIX-domain `AF_UNIX` other for INTERNET-domain `AF_INET`. Both are working fine!

`listen()` is called **for backlog queue length = 3** in `both servers`

```
listen(sockfd, 3);
```

**In UNIX domain (AF_UNIX):**  While one client is connected with server, If I try to connect more clients to server. Three are kept in queue, and request of fourth is declined. (as I desired - 3 in waiting queue).

**In INTERNET domain (AF_INET):**  Request of more than three are kept in a pending queue.

Why isn't a request from a fourth client rejected, even when the backlog queue length is three? And why is the behavior of `listen()` (and others) protocol dependent?

Comment: I don't really understand your intention... why would you ever want to reject a client just because the queue is full?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I mean it should be rejected if I given waiting queue length. And I want to know about this.

Comment: I think any API parameter that doesn't act the way we expect should bother us, because it implies we don't understand it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Operating systems actually use larger queues for incoming TCP connections than the one specified to `listen()`. How much larger depends on the operating system.

```
 listen(int socket_fd, int backlog)
```

For a given listening socket kernal maintains two queue.

1. An incomplete connection queue - for which SYN has been come but three-way handshaking (TCP) is not done completely. (SYN_RCV state)
2. A complete connection queue - Three-way handshaking done. (ESTABLISHED state)

*backlog* argument historically specify sum of both queues. But there is no formal definition of what *backlog* means.

Berkeley-derived implementation add a fudge factor to the backlog. So total queue `length = factor * backlog`.

A very detailed and deep explanation given in a book by W. Richard Stevens. Also a table showing the values for seven operating systems can be found in Stevens, Fenner, Rudoff, "[Unix Network Programming: The Sockets Network API](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=unix%20network%20programming%20the%20sockets%20network%20api%20volume%201%20third%20edition%20google%20books&source=bl&ots=Kr5xNpglTq&sig=w06efLjz6Qsl2Z6sCWrDv0XYIZk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QON7UNuXDobUrQeT_ICADQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)", Volume 1, Third Edition, Page 108.

Comment: For example on Linux 2.4.7 a `backlog` of 3 given to `listen()` results in up to 6 connections being queued.

Comment: CentOS 6.6 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
The backlog queue is backlog parameter +1

Answer (score 4):

The platform is entitled to adjust the specified backlog up or down, according to its minimum and its default. These days the default is more like 500 than five, which is where it started in about 1983. You can't rely on it being what you specified, and there is no API for finding out what it really is, and there is no apparent valid application reason for wanting it to be shorter than the default.

Comment: Some people try to use it as a limit on the number of concurrent connections. It isn't.