# accept() blocks (while pending connections)

Tags: c, sockets

I've noticed this weird problem with accept. I have a server that runs on FreeBSD and a client that runs on Windows .

Everything works just fine, but I've started to make some stress tests. I've noticed that after 1000 connections from

the client, the server just stops accepting any new connections. Any idea why ?

I'm guessing is something to do with TCP protocol handshake, but did anyone else noticed that ? Any solutions ?

## Server

```
    socket() // ipv4
    bind()
    listen(... , 0xFFFF)

    while (true) {
        sock=accept(socket, NULL, NULL);
        if (sock<=0)
            break;
        close(sock);
    }
```

## Client

```
    int count=0;
    while (true) {
        count++;
        socket(...)
        connect(...)
        close(...)
        fprintf(stderr, "Count: %i\r", count);
    }
```

After 1000 connections or so, the server blocks in accept.

I've set kern.ipc.maxsockets to 65535, but no effect.

Comment: May be you find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893379/listen-queue-length-in-socket-programing-in-c Check the linked page

Comment: All available sockets stuck in TIME_WAIT?

Comment: Some suggested tools to look at: [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), [`netstat(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be testing for any errors. I suggest you do that. I suspect you will find that the problem is that the *client* has stopped connecting, due to port exhaustion.

This kind of testing proves nothing. You aren't going to have single clients that connect and disconnect at the maximum rate.

Comment: When testing servers like this, I reduce the TIME_WAIT interval to 6 seconds, (but need to be careful 'cos global setting, so set back after tests).

Comment: EJP, the I'm not testing for errors. I've run the test using two clients on different stations. Martin James: yes, TIME_WAIT interval solved it, thanks!

Comment: @EduardSuica So your test is worthless. Run it again but this time put in some proper error checking at both ends.