# CLOSE_WAIT TCP states despite closed file descriptors

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

My Linux server application listens to port `8000` and closes all its file descriptors (FDs) correctly using `close()`.

Nevertheless, I sometimes observe up to 3000 `CLOSE_WAIT` TCP connections:

```
# netstat -antp | grep CLOSE_WAIT
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp      149      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:49630         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      236      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:48440         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      251      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:41748         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      149      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:46064         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      251      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:56654         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      251      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:37502         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      251      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:56976         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp      251      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:36416         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
... ~3000 more of these ...
```

(`netstat` is running as `root` so there's no missing data.)

I know `CLOSE_WAIT` would occur when the server application does not `close()` an FD connected to a socket. This is explained in the TCP state diagram of [RFC793](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) (nicer rendering e.g. [here](https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/%7Eagupta/cs340/project2/TCPIP_State_Transition_Diagram.pdf)) and also in e.g. https://blog.cloudflare.com/this-is-strictly-a-violation-of-the-tcp-specification/

But I know that my server does `close()` correctly because `ls -1 "/proc/$(pidof myserver)/fd" | wc -l` on the server process shows only 90 open FDs, not 3000.

Further evidence for correct closing is that `netstat -p` as shown above list no program associated with the port (see `CLOSE_WAIT  -`).

Some collection of other unsolved cases where `CLOSE_WAIT  -` is shown without associated process:

- [How do I remove a CLOSE_WAIT socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912370/how-do-i-remove-a-close-wait-socket-connection#comment117325428_61139251)
- https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/nfs-lock-services-are-affected-due-to-firewall-shielding-of-some-ports/thread/667243322445545472-667213878863474688
- https://serverfault.com/questions/311009/netstat-shows-a-listening-port-with-no-pid-but-lsof-does-not/847910#847910
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/orphaned-connections-in-close-wait-state

  - Here the `CLOSE_WAIT`s with `-` as process look like they are from the client side.

So the question:

**How can this many more `CLOSE_WAIT` states exist than open socket FDs?**

**Why is Linux contradicting itself regarding the output of `/proc/$PID/fd` and `netstat`, how can it be that `CLOSE_WAIT  -` can occur *at all* given that `CLOSE_WAIT` must have an unclosed socket (FD) associated with it?**

Comment: Does your server do any forking? and if so do both parent and child processes close the accepted sockets?

Comment: are you sure the client is ALSO closing their side of the connection?, if they never do then the connection will be left in that state.

Comment: @CarloArenas That's not correct. If the client wasn't closing its end he could never get *into* CLOSE_WAIT: the connection would remain ESTABLISHED.

Comment: @user207421: I didn't check recently, but AFAIK it can't be ESTABLISHED if the server side closes it.

Comment: @CarloArenas It can't be CLOSE_WAIT unless the client *has* closed it and the server *hasn't*.

Comment: @user207421: using the code provided in my solution you could also reproduce that scenario (ex: calling bye in the client) but I would expect such an scenario to be more visible in the server, hence why I assumed the problem is in the client.

Comment: @user207421 "If the client wasn't closing its end he could never get into CLOSE_WAIT: the connection would remain ESTABLISHED." That is wrong. The server closing the socket moves the connection state from ESTABLISHED to FIN_WAIT_1 unless it has already received a FIN from the client (in which case it would already be in CLOSE_WAIT state). The transition from ESTABLISHED to FIN_WAIT_1 doesn't require anything of the client.

Comment: @user207421 "_Does your server do any forking?"_ - My server does sometimes do fork+exec, but this does not seem to happen during my problem: I have checked both `systemctl status` (systemd to my knowledge starts programs in a cgroup so that it can reliably show any children, including nasty cases like double-forking) and it is empty, as well as `htop` which also contains no additional processes during the problem. So I am reasonably sure that the problem is not forking related. Also, if any FDs were inherited, shouldn't the child still show up under `PID/Program name` in `netstat`?

Comment: @GilHamilton But the server hasn’t closed the socket. Otherwise we couldn’t possibly be in CLOSE_WAIT. Nothing incorrect about it.

Comment: @GilHamilton Yes, the statement of @user207421 that _"the connection would remain ESTABLISHED"_ is inaccurate, but the previous (and more relevant) part of the sentence, _"If the client wasn't closing its end he could never get into CLOSE_WAIT"_, is right. Thus it does answer @CarloArenas's _"are you sure the client is ALSO closing their side of the connection?"_ question with "yes": We observe `CLOSE_WAIT` on the server, so the client must have closed.

Comment: @user207421 _"But the server hasn’t closed the socket. Otherwise we couldn’t possibly be in CLOSE_WAIT."_ -- but the server has no open FDs! So the server _must_ have closed the socket, as (to my knowledge) to have an open socket, you must have an FD.

Comment: I believe the CLOSE_WAIT state over the `netstat` and `ls` outputs. You will certainly find that this is a socket leak somewhere.

Comment: @user207421 But this is Linux. `/proc/pid/fd` is one of its most fundamental interfaces; that being bugged would be pretty weird. If there's no socket FD in there, there is nothing the application can close. It seems more likely that the server does call close(), and the kernel via some mechanism keeps the socket in `CLOSE_WAIT` anyway.

Comment: It isn't a 'fundamental interface': it is an observation point, bolted onto the side. CLOSE_WAIT *is* a fundamental interface. Don't look for bugs in the system when you could be looking for bugs in your own code.

Comment: Sorry. I was seeing `CLOSE_WAIT` and reading `TIME_WAIT`. I'll show myself out.

Comment: @user207421 _"Don't look for bugs in the system when you could be looking for bugs in your own code."_ You're arguing above that `/proc/pid/fd` shows incorrect content. That would be a bug in the system, not in my code.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of my conversation with @user207421 is correct. yes that part of his argument that you quote is correct and shows I was confused by assuming the CLOSE_WAIT I was seeing were in the server side, but it doesn't imply that the client DID close the socket, neither that the bug is in the system and not your code.

Comment: after looking at some mocked scenarios just remember one with a server written in java (using actors) that was not closing its sockets cleanly at restart and therefore was leaving all those CLOSE_WAIT sockets from the previous generation.  At least in your example, there is no pid associated with those errors shown, so might it be a similar case?

Comment: @CarloArenas "_was not closing its sockets cleanly at restart and therefore was leaving all those CLOSE_WAIT sockets from the previous generation_" -- Interesting idea, but my server did not restart (I can see it in the process's uptime: A few minutes after those `CLOSE_WAIT`s appear, it's already been running for hours).

Comment: @nh2 then it was maybe coming from one of the forked versions which obviously wouldn't close ALL filehandles on exit if they are not CLOEXEC in the parent; eitherway the sockets DON'T have a process associated with them so can't be coming from your running server.

Comment: can you confirm that when you said "close(fd) correctly" you have confirmed that no error was returned from the close() calld and therefore there is no "double close bug" in your server?

Comment: how are those sockets being cleared?, is an application restart enough?, for how long do they linger?, if they stay after the server process is gone is there any network traffic going on?, are there any other sockets without a process in a different state than CLOSE_WAIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

**A `CLOSE_WAIT` state without associated process occurs when a client waiting in the Linux kernel's `listen()` backlog queue disconnects before the user-space application `accept()`s it.**

This is easily reproducible with `netcat`, see below.

A summary of existing commentary on this question:

- My intuition in the above comments was correct that if no associated process is shown, it must be involving only the kernel, and not my program's file descriptors.
- Commenters' suggestions are incorrect that these process-less `CLOSE_WAIT`s are created by the server forgetting to call `close()`.
- Commenters' suggestions are incorrect that the kernel's display of `/proc/<pid>/fd` is somehow bugged.

### Repro with `nc`

Short repro summary (read below for explanations):

```bash
nc -l 1234
nc localhost 1234
nc localhost 1234         # press Ctrl+C here
ss -tapn 'sport = :1234'  # shows process-less `CLOSE-WAIT`
```

###### Terminal 1 ("server"):

```bash
nc -v -l 127.0.0.1 1234
```

This creates a socket (and calls `listen(..., 1)` on it with `backlog` queue length `1`, and calls `accept()` to wait for a connection.

(Can be verified with `strace`.)

Aside:

- This queue is called the "accept queue" ([great in-depth article about it](http://arthurchiao.art/blog/tcp-listen-a-tale-of-two-queues/)), containing connections *to be `accept()`ed*, but I'll refer to it as the `listen()` queue here because its size is determined by `listen()` and its life time is determined by the socket returned by `listen()`.
- Linux (`6.1.51` in my case) actually sets the real queue size to `backlog + 1`, so the queue really has 2 slots.
  I haven't researched why this is, but it is mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893379/listen-queue-length-in-socket-programing-in-c#comment45652724_12893574) and I've experimentally verified it:
  For a `listen(, ...)`, 3 clients can connect to the above netcat server (1 `accept()`ed, 2 in the queue), and only the 4th one will hang without a connection.
- The passed `backlog` size can be observed as the `Send-Q` field in the `ss -tlpn 'sport = :1234'` output below.

---

###### Terminal 2 ("client A"):

```bash
nc -v -4 127.0.0.1 1234
```

This connection makes `accept()` return on the server.

---

###### Terminal 3 ("client B"):

```bash
nc -v -4 127.0.0.1 1234
```

This connection fills an open slot in the server's `listen()` queue. It is not `accept()`ed.

Now, press `Ctrl+C` to cancel this `nc`.
This creates the `CLOSE_WAIT` state from the question.

### Observing `ss` output

If we run the above repro while watching `sudo watch -n1 --exec ss -tapn 'sport = :1234'` in another terminal, we can observe the state after each above step:

```
# After the server is started, we see the listening socket with a `Recv-Q` of `0`:

State  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port Process
LISTEN 0      1          127.0.0.1:1234      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("nc",pid=3613079,fd=3))

# After client A is started, we see the listening socket with a `Recv-Q` of `0`
# because client A was `accept()`ed:

State  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN 0      1          127.0.0.1:1234      0.0.0.0:*     users:(("nc",pid=3613079,fd=3))
ESTAB  0      0          127.0.0.1:1234    127.0.0.1:52190 users:(("nc",pid=3613079,fd=4))

# After client B is started, we see the listening socket with a `Recv-Q` of `1`
# because client B has not yet been `accept()`ed and is in the queue:

State  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN 1      1          127.0.0.1:1234      0.0.0.0:*     users:(("nc",pid=3613079,fd=3))
ESTAB  0      0          127.0.0.1:1234    127.0.0.1:42420
ESTAB  0      0          127.0.0.1:1234    127.0.0.1:52190 users:(("nc",pid=3613079,fd=4))
```

In the last step, we can already observe an `ESTAB` connection with `Process` being empty.
This is because indeed the connection is esablished -- but only with the server's kernel, not the server process, since the process has not yet `accept()`ed the connection.

The kernel does the TCP SYN-ACK-ACK handshake for us, thus the TCP connection is established in the kernel, before `accept()` happens.

Now after client B disconnects, we see the `CLOSE-WAIT` without process:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN     1      1          127.0.0.1:1234      0.0.0.0:*     users:(("nc",pid=3621113,fd=3))
ESTAB      0      0          127.0.0.1:1234    127.0.0.1:52628 users:(("nc",pid=3621113,fd=4))
CLOSE-WAIT 1      0          127.0.0.1:1234    127.0.0.1:45096
```

And `Recv-Q` is still `1`, so the disconnected connection is still in the kernel queue!

### Observing `netstat` output

Same with `netstat`:
`sudo watch -n1 'netstat -antpe | grep 1234'`

We see some more lines because `netstat` cannot do the convenient `'sport = :1234'` filtering that `ss` provides, so we see the client-side sockets too:

```
# After the server is started:

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       62603813   3621113/nc

# After client A is started:

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       62603813   3621113/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52628         127.0.0.1:1234          ESTABLISHED 1000       62608860   3621978/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          127.0.0.1:52628         ESTABLISHED 1000       62603814   3621113/nc

# After client B is started:

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:1234          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       62603813   3621113/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52628         127.0.0.1:1234          ESTABLISHED 1000       62608860   3621978/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          127.0.0.1:52628         ESTABLISHED 1000       62603814   3621113/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45096         127.0.0.1:1234          ESTABLISHED 1000       62609455   3622106/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          127.0.0.1:45096         ESTABLISHED 0          0          -
```

Again, here we have the first sought `-` as `PID/Program name` for the `ESTABLISHED` connection.

This also answers this question:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387574/netstat-output-is-established-no-program-name-attached-what-is-the-issue

And after the disconnect of client B:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:1234          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       62603813   3621113/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52628         127.0.0.1:1234          ESTABLISHED 1000       62608860   3621978/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          127.0.0.1:52628         ESTABLISHED 1000       62603814   3621113/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45096         127.0.0.1:1234          FIN_WAIT2   0          0          -
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:1234          127.0.0.1:45096         CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -
```

That's our `CLOSE_WAIT` with `-` process.

### More minimal repro with Python

Since `nc` may change what exactly it does over time (e.g. the system calls it makes), here's a similar TCP server in Python to make it extra clear what's happening on the server:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:  # TCP
  s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
  s.listen(1)
  while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    print(f"Got client {addr} as FD {conn.fileno()}")
    action = input("Press enter to close the current connection and call accept() again, or enter 'close-socket' to close the entire socket... ").strip()

    if action == "close-socket":
      s.close()
      input("Socket closed, press enter to terminate... ")
      exit()
    else:
      conn.close()
```

### Why the `CLOSE_WAIT` without process exists and how to get rid of it

The kernel keeps the disconnected `CLOSE_WAIT` connection in the queue defined by `listen()` without an associated process until either:

- the server `close()`s the socket returned by `listen()`, or
- the server `accept()`s the already-disconnected connection.

Accepting the already-disconnected connection will succeed: `accept()` will hand the server an FD.
This converts the `CLOSE_WAIT` without process into a `CLOSE_WAIT` *with* process.
The server may now call `close()` on the FD to close the connection and resolve the `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

Calling `close()` on the socket returned by `listen()` tears down the entire kernel queue, thus `CLOSE_WAIT` disappears immediately.

### Summary

- Process-less `CLOSE_WAIT`s are connections that entered the `listen()` queue and were terminated by the other side sending TCP `FIN` *before* being taken out of the `listen()` queue before our process `accept()`s them.
- They live in the kernel.
- They have no file descriptor (FD) associated with them, because the `accept()` that would assign them an FD has not happened yet.
- This explains why there can be more `CLOSE_WAIT`s than file descriptors.

The question's problem with 3000 such process-less `CLOSE_WAIT`s suggests that the server is not `accept()`ing connections.
This might be due to a bug, or because the server process is busy doing something else (e.g. garbage collection or running some other functions).
Thus the queue fills up.
The server must have called `listen(, 3000)` or higher. Indeed, I can see `Send-Q` is `4096` in `ss -tlpn 'sport = :8000'`.
When the queued clients eventually give up due to some timeout, the queued `ESTABLISHED` connections become queued `CLOSE_WAIT` connections.

Thus, the next step for solving the issue with up to 3000 `CLOSE_WAIT` connections should be figuring out why the server stops to call `accept()`.

Comment: Thank you very much @CarloArenas for your comments and shared example code! It helped me find the minimal repro.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios where this could be observed, but without specifics on your server implementation is impossible to answer this question effectively.

First, lets clarify that you can't expect to see in /proc/$PID/fd the filehandles of connections that are NOT associated with your process (which is what is indicated by not having your process id in the last column of the output shown), so there is no inconsistency at all, and you are just probably confused by the fact that those sockets were associated with your application at some time based on the port number used, but obviously not with the currently running process, or at least weren't `accept()` by it, as shown in this example of case 1, below:

```
root@debian:~# ls -al /proc/1157/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 carenas carenas  0 Oct 29 22:39 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 carenas carenas  0 Oct 29 22:39 ..
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:39 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:39 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:39 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:39 3 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:39 4 -> 'socket:[23882]'
root@debian:~# ls -al /proc/1199/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 carenas carenas  0 Oct 29 22:51 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 carenas carenas  0 Oct 29 22:51 ..
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:51 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:51 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:51 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:51 3 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:51 4 -> 'socket:[23882]'
lrwx------ 1 carenas carenas 64 Oct 29 22:51 5 -> 'socket:[22177]'
root@debian:~# netstat -antpe | grep 7777
tcp        2      0 0.0.0.0:7777            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       23882      1157/./fork         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60574         127.0.0.1:7777          ESTABLISHED 1000       21053      1198/perl           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:60574         ESTABLISHED 1000       22177      1199/./fork         
tcp        5      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:59690         CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -                   
tcp        5      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:44830         CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -
```

Second, you are correct that if your application does `close()` then you shouldn't see the sockets in CLOSE_WAIT, but your application might had not done so because:

1. those connections were stuck BEFORE your application was able to handle them, and so the socket was closed by the client before your application had a chance to do so.
2. with multiple threads, process and maybe even signal handlers all involved the fd might had been changed, so unless the return state from close() was checked it might had not been effective at all, this is specially likely if your application is relying instead on the OS closing all filehandles at `exit()` and might not even provide a default signal handler for SIGCHLD which might result in the process being left as a zombie.

An interesting example of case 2 (the original), but they are correlated anyway, because of the shared sockets is shown below:

```
# netstat -antpe | grep 7777
tcp        3      0 0.0.0.0:7777            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       23882      1157/./fork         
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:37786         CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -                   
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:34022         CLOSE_WAIT  0          0          -                   
tcp        4      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:60150         ESTABLISHED 0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60150         127.0.0.1:7777          ESTABLISHED 1000       21228      1406/perl      
# netstat -antpe | grep 7777
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7777            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       23882      1157/./fork         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          127.0.0.1:60150         ESTABLISHED 1000       24277      1524/./fork         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60150         127.0.0.1:7777          ESTABLISHED 1000       21228      1406/perl
```

Here the client got a non responsive server and was hung, until much later when the non response server was finally reaped, leaving it connected to a socket without a pid until eventually moving its connection to another server process "officially".

Finally, the extreme disbalance between working fd and the number of them in CLOSE_WAIT mean there is a severe problem in your application, the high numbers in the receive queue might be an indicative that the server become unresponsive, so this might be the sideffect of clients aggresively closing connections and making the problem worse by retrying.

Making sure that there are no shared sockets between processes and that there is nothing that would block the listener socket (ex: some garbage collection) would likely help. If this is just a capacity problem then shortening the listen queue and scaling horizontally might be the best option forward.

Comment: (1) is meaningless as far as I can see. (2) is not correct. The ACK goes to the socket, not to the FD. All processes will ‘see it,s affect. (3) is also incorrect: `close()` doesn’t really have any `return state` to check. The only ways it can fail are EBADF or a linger timeout, which is rarely used.

Comment: @user207421 I was trying to avoid making my answer too complicated, but (1) applies when the listener socket is not responsive, I had code to show that clearly if interested but I wanted to avoid discussing bugs that might not be relevant, and we still don't know how the code in the server with the problem looks. (2) this applies if the application shares fd (including an epoll queue), not all might see its effect if EPOLLONESHOT. (3) applies exacly to EBADF, if the fd is shared by all threads, it might had been changed to -1 after some other thread closed it for example.

Comment: (1) If the client closes the connection before the server accepts it, it is closed by TCP and removed from the backlog queue. The server app will never see it. (2) ‘ACK from the client went to the other one’ is meaningless, and ACK doesn’t determine poll behaviour.. Your (3) is valid once explained. The problem here is certainly a socket leak in the server, whatever the OP may say or think.

Comment: @CarloArenas Could you elaborate on how you created the `CLOSE-WAIT` entries without associated process in your `ss` output? I have not managed to do that with your scripts, but it seems you did!

Comment: @nh2: I used a newer but even buggier server implementation (this time in C, to avoid the failsafes from nodejs and perl discussed before) and using the few hints you had provided so far about your problematic one, but which code or bugs aren't relevant to this discussion. Replicating case 1 shouldn't be difficult to do with any of those though, but as explained before I will suggest instead to focus on your original code.

Comment: @user207421: (1) not always. they might be left in the listen() queue and then provided by accept(), but since they are already closed they won't be useful by the server, a well behaving server might notice that, but while there is no answer to my question about that I suspect there might not be error checks from read()/recv() or close() in this one.

Comment: @CarloArenas Could you share the code and invocation with which you managed to repro the above? With my real-world server, I have not been able to repro at-will: Sometimes it happens 3 times per day, sometimes it doesn't happen for weeks. The fact that you managed to repro it above in short time gives me hope that we could use that to make a minimal, reliable repro.

Comment: @nh2: frankly they are just too ugly, after all they have all the bugs I could think of that your server might have. I still think it would be better to focus on your code, and apply the lessons learned there. BTW had you checked your close() calls as suggested a couple of times already?

Comment: @CarloArenas Please, share the code if you can. It can be e.g. via a GitHub repo or similar if you prefer. Nobody cares about "ugliness of code" trying to reproduce a difficult production problem that takes servers down. An ugly reproducer is better than no reproducer. I have checked all `close()` calls I'm aware of and their error checking looks correct to me. Even if I missed one, it would still not yield an improvement, because `man 2 close` explains that "See NOTES for a discussion of why `close()` should not be retried after an error.". So after failed close, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Apologies, should had been clearer. Yes, there is nothing you can do, but at least we will know when those CLOSE_WAIT connections are being created and maybe infer by that what is causing it. As I explained before, maybe your server is over capacity at times, and the listener socket can't keep up, or maybe there is a particular nasty client that is timing out too quickly, or maybe your sockets are lingering for too long, or the clients are too slow or the payload is too big or the compression is not being negotiated correctly or there is some network bottleneck, or your process is swapping.

Comment: @user207421 _"(1) If the client closes the connection before the server accepts it, it is closed by TCP and removed from the backlog queue."_ -- This is wrong. It's exactly the opposite, and that's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355636/close-wait-tcp-states-despite-closed-file-descriptors/77420709#77420709): Closed closed before `accept()` are not removed from the listen queue; they stay in as process-less `CLOSE_WAIT`s.

Comment: @nh2: this was "case 1" which as I said could be reproduced with almost any version of the server (though I like your version with `nc`), to "improve" the situation you can change the clients to forcibly close the connection as shown with the [shared](https://github.com/carenas/buggy-tcpserver) client`--connect=reset` argument.

Comment: @CarloArenas Yes, that is right: Your case (1) was the correct guess. And indeed even with your initial Perl examples it could be reproduced, but I was missing the information that one needed to start >= 7 Perl clients simultaneously for reproducing it, because the server used `Listen => 5,`.